# why cant my card be placed in the middle of the screen in flutter

Tags: flutter, user-interface, widget, center, card

I try to place several center in the class file, there will only be 2 issue, one is the center does not work, another one will be error, did I place something wrong in my code?
Im not sure what did my widgets went wrong or Im confuse with the widgets

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:hupcarwashemployee/user_model/employee.dart';

import '../user_model/assignment.dart';

class UpdateAssignStatus extends StatefulWidget {
  final String id;
  UpdateAssignStatus(
      {required this.id});

  @override
  State<UpdateAssignStatus> createState() => _UpdateAssignStatusState();
}

class _UpdateAssignStatusState extends State<UpdateAssignStatus> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Assign'),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            StreamBuilder<List<Assignment>>(
              stream: read(widget.id.toString()),
              builder: (context, snapshot){
                if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                  return const Center(
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                  );
                }
                if (snapshot.hasError) {
                  return const Center(
                    child: Text("some error occured"),
                  );
                }
                if(snapshot.hasData){
                  final userData = snapshot.data;
                  return Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      SizedBox(
                          height: 400,
                          width: 300,
                          child: ListView.builder(
                            itemCount: userData!.length,
                            itemBuilder: (context, index){
                              final assignment = userData[index];
                              return SizedBox(
                                height: 400,
                                width: 300,
                                child: Card(
                                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
                                  child: Column(
                                    children: [
                                      Table(
                                        children: [
                                          TableRow(
                                              children: [
                                                const Center(child: Text('Date', style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'MonMed'),)),
                                                Text(': ${assignment.date.toString()}', style: const TextStyle(fontFamily: 'MonMed'),),
                                              ]
                                          ),
                                          const TableRow(children: [SizedBox(height: 10,), SizedBox(height: 10,)]),
                                          TableRow(
                                              children: [
                                                const Center(child: Text('Customer Name', style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'MonMed'),)),
                                                Text(': ${assignment.custName.toString()}', style: const TextStyle(fontFamily: 'MonMed'),),
                                              ]
                                          ),
                                          const TableRow(children: [SizedBox(height: 10,), SizedBox(height: 10,)]),
                                          TableRow(
                                              children: [
                                                const Center(child: Text('Car Name', style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'MonMed'),)),
                                                Text(': ${assignment.carName.toString()}', style: const TextStyle(fontFamily: 'MonMed'),),
                                              ]
                                          ),
                                          const TableRow(children: [SizedBox(height: 10,), SizedBox(height: 10,)]),
                                          TableRow(
                                              children: [
                                                const Center(child: Text('Car Plate', style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'MonMed'),)),
                                                Text(': ${assignment.carPlate.toString()}', style: const TextStyle(fontFamily: 'MonMed'),),
                                              ]
                                          ),
                                          const TableRow(children: [SizedBox(height: 10,), SizedBox(height: 10,)]),
                                        ],
                                      )
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ),
                              );
                            },
                          )
                      ),
                    ],
                  );
                }
                return const Center(
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                );
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
  static Stream<List<Assignment>> read(String type) {
    final serviceCollection = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Assignment').where('id',isEqualTo: type);
    return serviceCollection.snapshots().map((querySnapshot) =>
        querySnapshot.docs.map((e) => Assignment.fromSnapshot(e)).toList());
  }
}
```

this [image] is the ui i wanted to see, like in the middle, a card with information, this image [image: phonescreen] is my current screen, i want the card to be the center of the screen, is it possible ?

Comment: please could you share the error

Comment: you want to center your list? @Lim

Comment: Clear up your widget layouts . You got nested Column & nested Container for nothing

Comment: i have modified the quesiton, right now im stuck, i dunno how to place the card at the middle

Comment: @Lim You always have one card?

Comment: ya just one card

Comment: so why are you using ListView? @Lim

Comment: because all my read functions use listview so i also use listview at here, i only know how to do read with list view

Comment: as the answer blow said you don't need listview for just one card. @Lim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

warp tour main column with center and put this `mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,` on it

Your code should be something like this:

```
Center(
    child: Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        SizedBox(
          height: 400,
          width: 300,
          child: Card(
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Table(
                  children: [
                    TableRow(children: [
                      const Center(
                          child: Text(
                        'Date',
                        style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'MonMed'),
                      )),
                      Text(
                        ': data',
                        style: const TextStyle(fontFamily: 'MonMed'),
                      ),
                    ]),
                    const TableRow(children: [
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 10,
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 10,
                      )
                    ]),
                    TableRow(children: [
                      const Center(
                          child: Text(
                        'Customer Name',
                        style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'MonMed'),
                      )),
                      Text(
                        ': data',
                        style: const TextStyle(fontFamily: 'MonMed'),
                      ),
                    ]),
                    const TableRow(children: [
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 10,
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 10,
                      )
                    ]),
                    TableRow(children: [
                      const Center(
                          child: Text(
                        'Car Name',
                        style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'MonMed'),
                      )),
                      Text(
                        ': data',
                        style: const TextStyle(fontFamily: 'MonMed'),
                      ),
                    ]),
                    const TableRow(children: [
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 10,
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 10,
                      )
                    ]),
                    TableRow(children: [
                      const Center(
                          child: Text(
                        'Car Plate',
                        style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'MonMed'),
                      )),
                      Text(
                        ': data',
                        style: const TextStyle(fontFamily: 'MonMed'),
                      ),
                    ]),
                    const TableRow(children: [
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 10,
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 10,
                      )
                    ]),
                  ],
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  )),
```

The result:
[image]

this solution work if you have only one card as you mentioned above you only need one card

Comment: i have modified the question

Comment: oh the center was placed there, no wonder, thanks man